# For loop runs only once

Tags: java, for-loop

I am trying a for loop piece of code, where the user inputs the number of words he will write and then afterwards the words itself, and at the end it should check for specific requirements (words that sstart with K increase the count value and also the last word that started with K will get registered). However for some reason unknown to me, it just wont loop, no matter the input it just prints out everything on the code.

```
package Others;
import java.util.*;
public class StartsWithString 
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int wordNumber = 0;
        String words = "";
        int wordCount = 0;
        String lastWord = "";

        System.out.println("How many words are you going to write?: ");
        wordNumber = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Write the desired words: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < wordNumber; i++);
        {
            words = sc.nextLine();

            if(words.startsWith("K"))
            {
                wordCount++;
                lastWord = words;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("From a total of " + numriFjaleve + " words typed,);
        System.out.println(wordCount + " started with the letter K.");
        System.out.println("The last word typed which began with the letter K was: " + lastWord);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < wordNumber; i++);
```

You have a semicolon at the end of your loop definition. So your loop isn't actually a loop. It's a standalone `code block` which runs once. Remove the semicolon.

Comment: Nice catch and quickly.

Comment: @user1274820 Thanks. It's my first port of call given the problem statement.

Comment: Oh my God............. I'm embarrased but at the same time confused. How come Eclipse does not give out some kind of attention to that? I mean.....so sorry though, I am new to Java. Wasting your time. Sorry and thank you

Comment: My Eclipse shows a yellow marker, with tooltip "Empty control-flow statement". --- I've seen too many examples of this error, which is one of the reasons I prefer the start-brace at the end of the line, instead of on it's own line. Reduces likelyhood of that error, and don't waste code-lines. But it may be a policy thing, I know.

Comment: @Solocid It's a common error, don't worry. Your IDE should flag it with some warning, but in general you just get good at spotting semicolons where they shouldn't be. Your eyes will automatically adjust.